# RichTextBox height bind with grid row height works in xaml editor but not in program

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

In fact, I simply want to bind the height of RichTextBox to the height of the row in the grid, in a WPF application using VS 2015 community. 
And according to the XAML editor window, it did work, but when I launch the program/debug, it doesn't show the same result.
Here is the code :

```
<Grid x:Name="grid_tab1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Grid_test1_row0" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <RichTextBox 
            Background="black" Foreground="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="{Binding ElementName=Grid_test1_row0, Path=ActualHeight}"> 
        </RichTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

from the result showed in the program (.exe), this line seems not working :

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=Grid_test1_row0, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure why are you trying to do that. why not use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` only without  Height binding?

Comment: There must be other better solution to adapt the height of the box to the row height. I'm just curious, something like : "I found a bug", and would also like to know why something goes wrong in my program. I did try `(VerticalAlignment="Stretch")`, in the program, the box only has 1 line of height.

Comment: I would like to simply make the richtextbox fill the container. That was my original objetif...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Name field of the RowDefinition and replace with SharedGroupSize="Grid_test1_row0"

```
<Grid x:Name="grid_tab1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition SharedGroupSize="Grid_test1_row0" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <RichTextBox 
        Background="black" Foreground="White"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Height="{Binding ElementName=Grid_test1_row0, Path=ActualHeight}"> 
    </RichTextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I think it should be SharedSizeGroup and not SharedGroupSize